# Using class in <td> element - styling

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very basic question but I cant figure it out with standard approach. I have a table in which I am trying to do a different styling for one column. I thought that the easiest way to do this would use a class="class" property inside this column and then apply styling on it but it doesnt work.

This is exmaple of my table (its filled with JSON objects but its not important now):

```
<table id="logtable" class="pretty">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Payload</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${message.timestamp}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${message.sender}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${message.receiver}" /></td>
                    <td class="message"><c:out value="${message.payload}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the CSS I use (part of it):

```
table.pretty tbody td {
    text-align: center;
    background: #DEE7EF;
}
```

This works but when I try to style the last column like this, it doesnt do anything:

```
table.pretty tbody td .message {
    text-align: left;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: `td.message` is `<td class="message">` whilst, `td .message` is `<td><div class="message">` - the space denotes it to start looking for a `child` node of `<td>` with `.message`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need:

```
table.pretty tbody .message {
    text-align: left;
}
```

(skip the `td`).

This is because `.message` means basically "any element with the class `message`".

On the other hand, `td .message` means "any element with the class `message` inside any `td` element.

Answer (score 3):

You have space betweeb td and message,

**replace**

```
table.pretty tbody td .message {
```

**with**

```
table.pretty tbody td.message {
```

`td .message` this css selector means you are selecting .message which parent is td.
while `td.message` means `td` having `message` class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
table.pretty tbody td.message {
    text-align: left;
}
```

I believe the td .message is trying to find a child to the td-element with a class of "message".

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/